# Assistance: "A Gomory cut problem"

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming

Hope everything is operating smoothly for everyone here. I am working on a simple problem involving Gomory cutting planes and am having some trouble.

**Problem**

Consider the following LPP:

\begin{alignat*}{4}
\text{Maximize} \quad \quad \quad x_1 + x_2 & {}{} & & {}{} & & {}{} &\\
\text{Subject To} \quad -3x_1 + 2x_2 & {}\leq{} & 2 & {}{} & & {}{} &  & {}{} &\\
4x_1 + x_2 & {}\leq{} & 8 & {}{} &  & {}{} &  & {}{} &\\
x_1, x_2 & {}\in{} & \mathbb{N}_0   & {}{} & & {}{} &  & {}{} &\\
\end{alignat*}

Employing the Simplex method to solve the LP's relaxation, we arrive at the following optimal tableau:

$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
z & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & \text{RHS}\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{4}{11} & \frac{3}{11} & \frac{32}{11} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac{1}{11} & \frac{2}{11} & \frac{14}{11} \\
\hline
-1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{3}{11} & -\frac{5}{11} & -\frac{46}{11}
\end{array}
$$

**Q**: Find two Gomory cutting planes that "chop off" the optimal solution to the LP relaxation  for this problem, one using the first row and the other using the second row of the tableau.

**My Attempt**

We know $x_3 = 2 + 3x_1 - 2x_2$ and $x_4 = 8 - 4x_1 + x_2$. Using the first row of the tableau, we see that $$ \text{frac}(\frac{4}{11})x_3 + \text{frac}(\frac{3}{11})x_4 \geq \text{frac}(\frac{32}{11}) \implies \frac{4}{11}x_3 + \frac{3}{11}x_4 \geq \frac{32}{11} - \bigg\lfloor \frac{32}{11} \bigg\rfloor = \frac{10}{11}$$ We can rewrite this inequality equation in terms of $x_4$, so $x_4 = 8 - 4x_1 + x_2 \geq -\frac{4}{3}x_3 + \frac{10}{3}$. Since $x_3= 2 + 3x_1 - 2x_2$, this implies that $x_2 \leq 2$. This is the first cut (not sure if I am doing this correctly). Now we can look at the second row of the tableau and see that $$ \text{frac}(-\frac{1}{11})x_3 + \text{frac}(\frac{2}{11})x_4 \geq \text{frac}(\frac{14}{11}) \implies -\frac{1}{11}x_3 + \frac{2}{11}x_4 \geq \frac{14}{11} - \bigg\lfloor \frac{14}{11} \bigg\rfloor = \frac{3}{11}$$
Proceeding in a similar manner as before, we can rewrite $x_3$ in terms of $x_4$, which gives us $x_3 \geq -3 + 2x_4$. Since $x_3 = 2 + 3x_1 - 2x_2 \geq -3 + 2x_4$ we get that $x_1 \geq 1$, which forms the second cutting plane (again, not sure if what I've done is accurate or right in any case).

So, the first cutting plane is $x_2 \leq 2$ and the second cutting plane is $x_1 \geq 1$.

Comment: Some among your readers haventt been introduced to Mr Gomory. Think always that references are welcome; for example [here](http://www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/genz/364/lessons/l603.pdf)

Comment: Hey @JeanMarie , thank you for including that! I just checked it out and it seem to be an excellent resource.

Comment: The fractional part should be nonnegative, which goes wrong in your second example. You can quickly check the correctness of a cut by plotting it and verifying if it invalidates integer points (which reveals that $x_1 \geq 1$ is indeed incorrect).

Comment: Ah, so is $\text{frac}(-\frac{1}{11}) = \frac{10}{11}$?

Comment: yes, and there is a typo where you say $x_4=8-4x_1+x_2$

Comment: @LinAlg And this would mean $x_3 \geq 10 - \frac{1}{5}x_4$, which means that $2 + 3x_1 - 2x_2 \geq 10 - \frac{1}{5}(8 - 4x_1 - x_2)$, which means $x_1 \geq \frac{32}{11} + x_2$

Comment: @LinAlg I will add Edits underneath my post given this new information (the miscalculation of $\text{frac}$ and the typo). I will be back in some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have:
$$x_1 - \frac{1}{11}x_3 + \frac{2}{11} x_4 = \frac{14}{11}. \qquad (1)$$
Since all variables are nonnegative, we can round down the coefficients and obtain a valid inequality:
$$x_1 - x_3 \leq \frac{14}{11}.$$
Since $x_1$ and $x_3$ are integer, this inequality is the same as:
$$x_1 - x_3 \leq 1.$$
If you subtract this from $(1)$, you obtain:
$$\frac{10}{11}x_3 + \frac{2}{11} x_4 \geq \frac{3}{11}.$$
Since $x_3 = 2+3x_1-2x_2$ and $x_4=8-4x_1-x_2$, this becomes:
$$\frac{10}{11}(2+3x_1-2x_2) + \frac{2}{11} (8-4x_1-x_2) \geq -\frac{3}{11},$$
which simplifies to the cut:
$$2x_1 - 2x_2 \geq -3.$$

Comment: Nice, thank you for your help with this problem!